# Browser freezes (OOM?) when computing a large file MD5 using JS Crypto library

Tags: javascript, hash

I am using Webpack, compiling a bundled JS file.

## The problem

I have a Worker that I am offloading the hashing work to. I pass a file and filesize to it. I previously did not use a Worker. However, when Chrome reacted badly to hashing a large file, I thought that the main thread was being blocked by the hashing mechanism. This could be a false assumption.

The code works correctly for small files. However, for large files, once reaching the part where the final hash is generated, Chrome shows this error:

[image: Chrome error message]

Firefox is a bit more helpful and shows this message:

> Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (out of memory)

However, the piping of data should alleviate this issue. `fileReaderStream` reads data in chunks of 1 MB.

## The code

```
import Crypto from 'crypto'
import fileReaderStream from 'filereader-stream'
import concat from 'concat-stream'
var progress = require('progress-stream');

self.onmessage = (event) => {
    switch (event.data.topic) {
        case 'hash': {
            var file = event.data.file;
            var filesize = event.data.filesize;

            let p1 = progress({
                length: filesize,
                time: 100 /* ms */
            });
            let p2 = progress({
                length: filesize,
                time: 100 /* ms */
            });

            p1.on('progress', function(progress) {
                console.log('p1', progress);
            });
            p2.on('progress', function(progress) {
                console.log('p2', progress);
            });

            let md5 = Crypto.createHash('md5');

            console.log("START HASH");
            var reader = fileReaderStream(file);
            reader.pipe(p1).pipe(md5).pipe(p2).pipe(concat((data) => {
                console.log("DONE HASH");
                console.log(data);
            }));

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

## Small file example (5,248 KB)

[image: Dev console log of uploading a small file]

## Large file example (643 MB)

[image: Dev console log of uploading a large file]

## Additional Information

Screenshot of memory usage. It takes up 3 GB in a few seconds.

[image: Memory issue chart]

Comment: there is a large amout of console.log output

Comment: @Jer That is only due to the progress stream. There is not that much of it, and when I remove it the same issue exists. (the progress stream is only in the example at all as an indicator to show the community where the issue lies)

Comment: How many memory does your server have?

Comment: This is my local development machine with 8GB of memory. Edit: I added an image of my local memory usage.

Comment: Google chrome does not allocate more than ~2Gb for JS runtime.

Comment: The issue is that it shouldn't be allocating that much at all. Given the streaming nature of the piping. The whole file shouldn't be in memory. Infact, it appears to be allocating over 3 times the filesize for no discernable reason.

Comment: Take a memory profiler then.

Answer (score 0):

So it could be worth using a different library if this one is poorly implemented with regards to memory management.

This javascript library is implemented by stanford - https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

You may also want to consider using a more secure hashing algorithm than md5 due to it's vulnerability to collisions via the birthday attack.